# Add pages to PDF using FPDF if pagecount is not divisible by 4

Tags: php, fpdf, fpdi

Im trying to print some fpdf generated PDFs but if the page total is odd or not divisible by 4 then printing to a booklet is causing me some issues

eg total pages = 73 printing to a booklet on A3 paper needs 4 pages per A3 sheet

If i use this script

```
$pageCount = 73;
if ($pageCount % 4 != 0) {
$newpagecount = $pageCount += 4 - ($pageCount % 4);
}

while ($pageCount < $newpagecount) {
    $pageCount++;
//add page here and keep looping until it gets to the divisble by 4 number
}
```

I get 76 which is correct and divisible by 4 what i need it to do is add a blank page to my source document until i get to the new divisible by 4 pageCount?

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your while loop simply add a call to the `AddPage` method to create new pages as needed.

```
while ($pageCount < $newpagecount) {
    $pageCount++;
    $yourpdf->AddPage(); //add page here and keep looping until it gets to the divisble by 4 number
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatley this does not work, to do a pagecount of a PDF it has to be output already (which it is) so i need to then add blank pages to this existing outputted PDF then output that as another PDF (if that makes sense)
so if i use

$pageCount = 73;
if ($pageCount % 4 != 0) {
$newpagecount = $pageCount += 4 - ($pageCount % 4);
}
echo "new pagecount = ".$newpagecount."<br>";
while ($pageCount < $newpagecount) {
 $pageCount++;
 $pdf->AddPage();
}
$pdf->Output("c:\\temp\\editd.pdf','F');

that generates a 1 page blank pdf

Comment: A PDF does not have to be output before knowing the page count. The count is maintained as the PDF is being created (as evidenced by the fact that you can put page numbers in the footer for example). Add your tests and the addition of extra pages to the creation of the original PDF instead of trying to do it after the fact.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction...
$pdf->cell(350,20,$pdf->PageNo().'{nb}',0,'C',false); gives me current page and total page count , all i need is total page count, how can i just get that?

Comment: $pdf->AliasNbPages().'{nb}' gives me just the total
Thanks again Dave wil ltry this

Comment: @Retroisbest If an answer solved your problem, consider accepting the answer. [Here's how](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/379718) and [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), then return here and do the same with the tick/checkmark till it turns green. This informs the community, a solution was found. Otherwise, others may think the question is still open and may want to post (more) answers. You'll earn points and others will be encouraged to help you. Welcome to Stack!

Comment: This is my code used right before i output to a PDF

while ($pageCount % 4 != 0)  {
$pageCount++;
$pdf->Addpage();
}

Thanks to Dave for pointing me in the right direction